# Magento, redirect the url from "www.domain.com/home" to base url "www.domain.com"

Tags: magento, url, radix, redirect

I am trying to configure how to redirect my magento website from `www.domain.com/home` to base url `www.domain.com`, it always redirecting to `www.domain.com/home`

UPDATE

Thanks Amit, I use your solution

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/accueil
RewriteRule ^(.*)accueil$ http://www.cabas-durables.fr/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but I got error at the browser says

> The page isn't redirecting properly

then I change the `$1` after http://www.cabas-durables.fr/$1 to `index.php`, then it shows "http://www.cabas-durables.fr/index.php" at the browser, then I bring it back to `$1` I got no error but it stays to "http://www.cabas-durables.fr/index.php"

I don't know where to change it to only "http://www.cabas-durables.fr/"

I will have problem with SEO if it not change

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be better to use htaccess.
 find

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
```

Then
Put the below code in  htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/home
RewriteRule ^(.*)home$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for reply, the code is already there as: `    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]` shall I change it? or ad your code, thank you

Comment: I found it, shall I write the code below it, and I have home page called "accueil", so shall I write `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/accueil` , Thank you

Comment: please check the code if it is correct before saving the file: `    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/accueil
    RewriteRule ^(.*)accueil$ http://www.cabas-durables.fr/$1 [R=301,L] 
`

Comment: The page isn't redirecting properly, I got this message in the browser

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to paste in the code that you tried but couldn't make work. Amit's answer is correct and I'm sure you or he will spot the typing error in your code if you typeset it into your question so we can all read it clearly.

Comment: yes it works, it was my fault I change all 302 to 301 in .htaccess file

Answer (score -1):

Create URL Redirect in admin panel.

Use tagret path - `"../"`; it will redirect to the homepage.