# Magento - Homepage Preview is different than the Homepage Live View

Tags: php, magento

I am new to Magento. My client assigned me a task. I completed the task mostly, but one thing that I don't understand and also my client don't understand. When I preview the home page from admin panel, I get this page opened.

[image: preview magento]

But I open live website, this page opens:
[image: live magento]

When I put content on CMS page in admin panel, it gets visible on page preview, as you can see the heading `Google Maps`, I put this string in content, but is not visible in the live page. What's going on there, I don't understand. Please help me to solve this problem.

Website URL: http://spacedookie.com/

Comment: Have you cleaned cache?

Comment: The URLs are different.  Guessing it's some kind of URL re-write issue.

Comment: @GerarddeVisser yes, I cleaned the cache, but in vain.

Comment: @Don I think it's not url redirect, because the .htaccess file is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://spacedookie.com/ is `site landing page` and `http://spacedookie.com/home is  cms  page.`

Magento have provide any cms page to set as landing for the site.
According you site your site default layout `is 1col but this cms page layout 2-col right`

You need redirection 301   `http://spacedookie.com/home` to `http://spacedookie.com/`
check 301 for [Magento, redirect the url from "www.domain.com/home" to base url "www.domain.com"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129310/magento-redirect-the-url-from-www-domain-com-home-to-base-url-www-domain-com/23129804)

Goto admin>CMS>Pages>Select your home page > then goto Design tab select page layout

[image]
    1colums and save it

Comment: I went to admin>CMS>Pages>Select your home page > then goto Design tab select page layout and selected 1 column, but nothing happens, still it redirects to landing page. OK, what to do, it need to put some custom php and html on landing page? When I put on CMS home page, it appears, but doesn't appear on landing page (base url page). How can I put on landing page?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `system >> Configuration >> Design` and check your selected package and theme under each scope. mainly under default config.